# Can I use cy.writeFile() to write a formatted txt file?

Tags: cypress, background-color

By my test script I want to display the background color (hex value) of some of my web element to a .txt file but I want to display like this **the background color of login button** hex value. The hex value will be good to be highlighted. Is there any way I can do it.

Comment: Please add the code you tried and also add the HTML of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a button that has a CSS as `color` and has a hex value `#000000` and has some text, You can do something like this.

```js
cy.get('button').then(($ele) => {
  cy.writeFile(
    'cypress/fixtures/colors.txt',
    'The background color of the element ' +
      $ele.text() +
      ' is ' +
      $ele.css('color'),
    {flag: 'a+'}
  )
})
```

If you have multiple elements with the same selector, you can just replace `then()` with `each()`

```js
cy.get('button').each(($ele) => {
  cy.writeFile(
    'cypress/fixtures/colors.txt',
    'The background color of the element ' +
      $ele.text() +
      ' is ' +
      $ele.css('color'),
    {flag: 'a+'}
  )
})
```

Your colors.txt file should look like this:

```js
The background color of the element Button-1 is #000000
The background color of the element Button-2 is #FFFFFF
...
...
...
```

The `{flag: 'a+'}` will make sure that all the new texts are added to the end of the file rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

No, `.txt` files generally do not have bold formatting, but you could use an HTML file.

Wrap the text with `<b>my text</b>`, and add `<br>` to give new line.

```js
const html = `<b>the background color of ${selector}</b> <span style="background-color: yellow">${hex}</span><br>`
cy.writeFile('cypress/backgroundColors.html', html, {flag: 'a+'})
```

**HTML output**

[image]

---

**Converting rgb to hex**

jQuery returns ***rgb*** not hex, but sometimes its `rgb(0, 0, 0)` and sometimes `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` (depending on what sets it).

Here's my full test that covers the conversion,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('hexBG', (selector) => {
  cy.get(selector)
  .invoke('css', 'background-color')
  .then(rgb => {
    const hex = (x) => ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    const rgb2hex = (rgb) => {
      const match = rgb.match(/^rgb(a*)\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)/);
      return "#" + hex(match[2]) + hex(match[3]) + hex(match[4]);
      }
    return rgb2hex(rgb)
  })
})

cy.visit('http://example.com')

const selector = 'h1'
cy.hexBG('h1')
  .then(hex => {
    const html = `<b>the background color of ${selector}</b> <span style="background-color: yellow">${hex}</span><br>`
    cy.writeFile('cypress/backgroundColors.html', html, {flag: 'a+'})
  })

cy.get('h1').invoke('css', 'background-color', 'green')  // make it more interesting

cy.hexBG('h1')
  .then(hex => {
    const html = `<b>the background color of ${selector}</b> <span style="background-color: yellow">${hex}</span><br>`
    cy.writeFile('cypress/backgroundColors.html', html, {flag: 'a+'})
  })
```

**HTML output**

[image]